# angular 2 cli very slow on first serve and a while refresh

Tags: performance, angular, refresh, command-line-interface

After using in angular for awhile i decided to move to angular 2.
I'm using the latest angular-cli version and latest node and npm.

I have a not brand new pc but it suits me well.
CPU: E7500
RAM: 4GB
Win7 64 bit

So i open the webstorm, wait a few second for it to load everything and the i type "ng serve", this command took 22s!!!
This is very slow, although this command took place only once, it's not so bad bat its is bad, right?

The second problem is very annoying,
after i change something in the code (html, css..) the refresh action took 7-8 second, this is nightmare for me and it's very frustrating!

Now, i know that the cli project is done a lot for me and i know it can cost me in a few second but i simple cant work like this especially with the refresh action.

1. Is this normal for cli or this is only because my pc?
2. Is there something i can do to speed up the refresh action?

Thanx

Comment: It's normal for current build.. CLI is still in beta and this is one of the issues they're working on at the moment.

Comment: I'm building a rather small project with 5 pages, and on an overclocked latest i7-6700K with 16GB RAM on Linux building to an SSD takes almost 8 seconds. If you go through the issues list on the angular-cli GitHub you will find, that you are not the only one. The team is aware of the problem and in later versions this should improve. By how much is hard to tell.

Comment: OK, i try out the original tour-of-heroes from here: https://github.com/johnpapa/angular2-tour-of-heroes
 and the refresh took even more, something about 15-18s. any suggestions??

Comment: You can always build your own development pipline (: I used custom gulp tasks few months back, with average rebuild time ~250ms. But maintaining and updating it is not easy, so using CLI (with all it's faults) is acceptable for me. You must decide for yourself...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the local RAM might help on this. I have 8GB RAM and it took more than 5 minutes to complete the great **ng-serve**.

Here is what I did to speed up the working.

1. I uninstalled the latest version of npm and node and went back to popular version instead of Latest.
2. Delete all the references , I meant about the previous projects build on it. Here you can delete the node_modules package only and then import just the component codes to the new project build with popular version of Node.js.
3. Compile it, @ first , it will take time to spin around and complete the actions but later, it will work faster!

** I know going back to the lesser version isn't a good practice but when it really eases your work, I think it's acceptable.